# GoPro Studio Editing HD Videos

Tags: video-editor, performance, studio

Looking at buying a MacBook Pro with this Spec:-

2.2GHz Quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.4GHz
16GB 1600MHz DDR3L SDRAM
256GB PCIe-based Flash Storage
Intel Iris Pro Graphics
Backlit Keyboard (British) & User's Guide (English)

Will this run the studio without any glitches etc etc. Thanks For your help Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this meets the minimum spec for the software then that would be your answer, reading the min spec it will be fine to run the software

Mac OS X 10.8 or later
Intel® Dual Core™ 
  Recommended: Intel Quad Core™ i7 or better
Any graphics card shipped with Intel® Dual Core™ Macs or better 
Recommended for 4K editing and playback: Intel HD4000 or better
4GB
Minimum: 5400 RPM internal drive
Recommended: 7200 RPM drive. 
If external, use Thunderbolt, USB 3.0, Firewire or eSATA 
Version 7.6 or greater

if there is something more specific you would like to know we would need the specifics then

Comment: Thanks Adam. Looks like I will buy a Mac this weekend:-).

Comment: Obviously making sure the Apple Mac is the right choice for you of course. dont just buy one if you are not 1000% sure it is for you, going by the question the specs are fine and would be the same answer if it was a Windows PC as the specs are enough to cope with it all

Comment: Only other thing I would mention is getting a external HDD or two for working on and backup and the SSD will fill up quick with GoPro files